# Is there a function to know where the heat diffusion started on a surface, at t=0

Tags: signal-processing, fft, graph-theory, heat

I am trying to find a way through Fourier transform, that if I know temperature of each vertex on a connected graph at time T, is there is a way to find out which vertex the heat diffusion started from at t=0, and led to the current temperature signal at time T.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This is not a question about programming. You need to solve an inverse problem, consider asking on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you post a minimal code snippet with your attempt people here might be able to help more. additionally it's work noting there's also https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What does "Fourier transform of a connected graph" even mean?  Is it a grid?  You can solve this kind of problem by decomposing the distribution into eigenvectors of diffusion equation.  In some special cases that means a Fourier transform, but not generally.